# Upgrade Twilio API

Tags: twilio

I want to upgrade number to 2010-04-01 version api, but I cannot find where to set this. According to 2010-04-01 API Changelog:

> To start using the new API, replace '2008-08-01' with '2010-04-01' in
>   your REST URIs, or set the API version on a per-phone number basis
>   using the phone numbers interface in your account portal.

Please help

Comment: Could you share the code you're using that you want to update?

Comment: I want to upgrade api to use 2010-04-01 version, not update. Use case is when someone trigger twilio number, voice url endpoint gets parameters from old 2008-08-01 api - Caller instead of From.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to update the weebhooks you get from Twilio from the 2008 version to the 2010 version you need to go into each phone number in the [Twilio dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming) and upgrade the API from the detail view of the phone number. There's a guide to upgrade here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/2010-04-01/upgrade-guide

If that doesn't help, drop me a line at philnash@twilio.com and I'll help you get it sorted.

**[edit]**

It appears that the option to upgrade the API version for a phone number no longer exists in the interface. If this is a problem, please raise a support ticket by emailing help@twilio.com and you can be upgraded manually.

Comment: Yea, I read the upgrade-guide, the problem is that I don't see version settings on number page of Twilio dashboard